# Same action in all model observer events in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a model observer class in my Laravel project. I have the same action on all the events triggered in a model lifecycle. Instead of having all events with the same action, I want the same action defined for all events in a single place without having all observer methods. How can I achieve this?

This is my function.

```
project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
```

As you can see below, **saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate()** is being called in all event methods. Is there any way to register this definition in a single place for all events?

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\TimeSheet;

class TimeSheetObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle events after all transactions are committed.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $afterCommit = true;

    /**
     * Handle the TimeSheet "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\TimeSheet  $timeSheet
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(TimeSheet $timeSheet)
    {
        project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the TimeSheet "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\TimeSheet  $timeSheet
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(TimeSheet $timeSheet)
    {
        project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the TimeSheet "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\TimeSheet  $timeSheet
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(TimeSheet $timeSheet)
    {
        project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the TimeSheet "restored" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\TimeSheet  $timeSheet
     * @return void
     */
    public function restored(TimeSheet $timeSheet)
    {
        project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the TimeSheet "force deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\TimeSheet  $timeSheet
     * @return void
     */
    public function forceDeleted(TimeSheet $timeSheet)
    {
        project()->saveSummaryOfLaborCostForTheDate($timeSheet->date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of observer you can used [event subscriber](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#event-subscribers). By using event subscriber can you define your single method in subscriber class and then point all model events to that method in `subscribe()`  method.